# How to access NodeJS GraphQL service in Python

Tags: python, node.js, graphql

I am new to GraphQL.
I have a graphQL service written in NodeJS. I have to use the service in building a data pipeline in python.

The query look like this

```
query = getStatement($Statement: {StatementInput}, $paginateBy: PaginateBy) {
  getStatement(StatementInput: {Statement}, paginateby: {paginateBy}) {
    status
    message
    statusCode
    metadata {
      page {
        number
        size
        totalPages
        totalElements
      }}}}

variables = {
       "StatementsInput": {
               "id": "XTYADC"
          },
          "Statement": {
"statementDate": "12-2018"
             },
           "paginateBy": {
 "size": 20,
   "pageNumber": 1
           }
}
```

I have the end point and using requests library.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a GraphQL server, all you need is a GraphQL client implementation. From official documentation, you can find the latest implementations of Python GraphQL client libraries according to your python version needs. Find more [here](https://graphql.org/code/#python-1)

For you could use the GQL package from https://github.com/graphql-python/gql like so,

```
from gql import gql, Client

client = Client(schema=schema)
query = gql('''
{
  hello
}
''')

client.execute(query)
```

> Keep in mind, that since GraphQL is a specification you could also
>   write a Client of your own. The GraphQL specification isn’t opinionated about the transportation layer, so it can be any. An example of HTTP implementation of it can be found at https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-graphql-client-library/

Comment: The client is already written in NodeJS. While I am trying to define variables directly like this $paginateby: {
pageNumber:20
size: 20
}, I get Syntax Error: Expected Name, found {' . Looks like this is very Nodejs specific query syntax.

Comment: @JohnRuby in your question you declare that the NodeJS is the GraphQL server and you need to consume graphQL API from a python service. So why you state that your client is already written in NodeJS? Could you amend your question with more details of both your GraphQL server and client?

Comment: I am a beginner so could not understand how to pass query and variables.  Found the solution. requests.post(url,json = {'query':query,'variables':variables}). This is the way the schema has been built